# ubuntu 14.10 update error

Tags: updates, 14.10

I can't update, i have this error when running **apt-get update** command!

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cooperjona/nitrotasks/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cooperjona/nitrotasks/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

what can i do?

Comment: check this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/548577/error-apt-get-update-on-ubuntu-14-10 hope this helps

Comment: @vembutech i cant find ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main

Comment: @AdhamEl-Deeb you've got a different ppa but it's depreciated. anyhow, instructions below on a manual install of nitro and how to fix your errors as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one of two things.

This ppa has not been updated since 2013 so it may be wise to not use it for now. You can however download the most recent version of nitrotasks from https://launchpad.net/~cooperjona/+archive/ubuntu/nitrotasks/+packages and install it manually.

First, to delete the outdated ppa open a terminal and execute the following commands:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cooperjona-ubuntu-nitrotasks-utopic.list*
```

Now, update your package list:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Finally, download the desired software directly from the ppa and install it:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~cooperjona/+archive/ubuntu/nitrotasks/+files/nitrotasks_1.5-0%7E31%7Esaucy1_all.deb
```

install it:

```
sudo dpkg -i nitrotasks_1.5-0~31~saucy1_all.deb
```

resolve dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: I've installed it and started it up just fine but haven't really done any tasks or whatnot but I can say that it starts up fine with no errors (14.10)